# How to test a LongPressDraggable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, automated-tests, widget-test-flutter

I want to test a LongPressDraggable in Flutter.
The WidgetTester provide methods like longPress or several drag methods.
But there is no "longPressDrag" or something like this.
The first idea was to run a longPress and a drag. But after the longPress the widget tester doesnt hold the widget and i can't drag it.

```
await tester.longPress(from);
await tester.timedDrag(from, offset, Duration(milliseconds: time));
```

A workaround is to use the timedDrag and run it super slow.
This works but takes a lot of time.

```
await tester.timedDrag(from, offset, Duration(seconds: 15));
```

Is there a correct way to test the widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `startGesture` method to start your own gesture. The "Finger is pressed" until you call `geseture.up()`. Between start and up use `gesture.moveTo` to move the cursor and `tester.pump(duration)` to stay still at a certain position to trigger the long-press.

Example code from the flutter repo in [draggable_test.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/widgets/draggable_test.dart#L285)

```dart
    final Offset firstLocation = tester.getCenter(find.text('Source'));
    final TestGesture gesture = await tester.startGesture(firstLocation, pointer: 7);
    await tester.pump();

    expect(targetMoveCount['Target 1'], equals(0));
    expect(targetMoveCount['Target 2'], equals(0));

    final Offset secondLocation = tester.getCenter(find.text('Target 1'));
    await gesture.moveTo(secondLocation);
    await tester.pump();

    expect(targetMoveCount['Target 1'], equals(1));
    expect(targetMoveCount['Target 2'], equals(0));

    final Offset thirdLocation = tester.getCenter(find.text('Target 2'));
    await gesture.moveTo(thirdLocation);
    await tester.pump();

    expect(targetMoveCount['Target 1'], equals(1));
    expect(targetMoveCount['Target 2'], equals(1));

    await gesture.moveTo(secondLocation);
    await tester.pump();

    expect(targetMoveCount['Target 1'], equals(2));
    expect(targetMoveCount['Target 2'], equals(1));

    await gesture.up();
    await tester.pump();
```